# How to read data to dask dataframe and remove bad lines

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, data-science, dask

I am attempting to aggregate a large (66gb) database with multiple lines of bad data using dask.

As dask has no remove bad lines functionality I am first reading in all data as a pandas dataframe and removing bad lines. I am then converting this to a dask dataframe. My code is as follows:

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client

```
#Groups the average Thresholds by NEATGeneration and finds the mean, standard deviation, minimum and maximum of the data
def group(df):
    res = df.groupby(df["NEATGeneration"]).agg({'averageThreshold': ['mean', 'std','max','min']}).compute()
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':

   Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=6,memory_limit='120GB')

   #Loads in the data as a pandas datframe inlcuding bad lines
   df = dd.read_csv("agentsvfitness.txt",error_bad_lines=False,usecols=["NEATGeneration","averageThreshold"])

   #Replaces elements in  the averageThreshold column that are not numeric with NA
   pd.to_numeric(df['averageThreshold'] , errors ='coerce') 

   #Removes rows with NA
   df = df.dropna()

   #runs the group() function in parallel
   df = group(df)

   #Sets all column names and prepares data for writing to csv
   df.columns = ['mean', 'std','max','min']

   #Writes aggregated data to a single csv file
   df.to_csv("averageThreshold.csv")
```

The issue I am running into is when the data has been incorrectly recorded in the following manner (bolded):

> **NEATGeneration,averageFitness,averageResourcesConsumed,averageThreshold**
>
> 0,8.32,0.8533333333333334,0.4819999999999999
>
> **0,8.486666666666666,1.7266666666666666.47333333333333333 #lacking " ,0 "**
>
> **0,8.0533333333333331.8466666666666667,0.4500000000000001 #lacking a " , "**
>
> 0,8.306666666666667,1.9466666666666668,0.44933131583851454

My current method is unable to remove these lines when reading in the data to a dask dataframe. Is there some way of removing these bad lines from an already existing dataframe? Else is there a way to read in only 'good' data (data with the correct number of datapoints)? I am running on a cluster with 24 CPUs and 120GB of memory.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, why can't you read the csv to dask? `df = dd.read_csv("agentsvfitness.txt", error_bad_lines=False)` setting err_bad_lines to False will drop the incorrect lines

Comment: @effy okay I have used `dd.read_csv("agentsvfitness.txt", error_bad_lines=False)` and have edited my code slightly to reflect this. Even with this, rows are still being read into the dataframe that have too little elements which is causing the groupby to crash.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is some combination of the `read_csv` keywords that will solve your problem, but I'm not very familiar with them, so I'm going to suggest an alternative approach.

You could use Dask Bag to read the lines of text as text rather than Pandas Dataframes.  You could then filter out bad lines with a Python function (perhaps by counting the number of commas or something) and then you could write this back out to text files, and then re-read with Dask Dataframe now that the data is a bit more cleaned up.  There is probably also some nice way to turn the Dask Bag into a Dask Dataframe without writing intermediate files to disk, but that's probably slightly more complex.